# Why MySQL does not provide stddev(distinct expression)?

Tags: mysql

I ask the question because some other numerical aggregates, like sum, avg or count support the distinct modifier. And other databases like Oracle or MSSQL support distinct modifier for stddev.

Comment: Because no one implemented it. You could also ask why they still don't support [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides)

Comment: And it doesn't even support some of the old stuff - `CHECK CONSTRAINT`s for example.

Comment: Does  `stddev` even make sense for distinct values?

Comment: Searching the MySQL bug tracker and including feature requests it doesn't look as though anyone has ever requested it. There's only 1 hit for stddev in total http://bugs.mysql.com/search.php?search_for=Stddev&status%5B%5D=Active&severity=all&limit=30&order_by=&cmd=display&phpver=&os=0&os_details=&bug_age=0&tags=&similar=&target=&last_updated=0&defect_class=all&workaround_viability=all&impact=all&fix_risk=all&fix_effort=all&triageneeded=

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer:  Standard Deviation is one of thousands of things that are so little used that it is not worth providing.

You can provide it, even in summary tables, by keeping

```
COUNT(*)
SUM(x)
SUM(x*x)
```

There are two stddev forumlas; they differ by only tiny amounts for large sets of data.  One of them can be reformulated using only those 3 aggregates.